# Finding an element that appears in a two-dimensional array, the most

Tags: multidimensional-array

In the data provided by the table (5 x 4, two-dimensional array) it can be seen that Bob has won the most events, at a total of 3 wins.

[image: table representing data]

How can I count and figure out who has their name appear the most times in the array? The names and size of the array are set by the user, so different values can appear.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use **HashMap**, with the name as the key and the number of times they appeared as their value, and then traverse the entire HashMap and find the one which has the highest value.
Let us take an example,

Suppose

`set(key,value)` is a function that takes a key(name eg. 'Bob') and corresponding value and add to the HashMap object hm,

`get(key)`, returns the number of times this key has appered in hm(HashMap object),

while traversing you can just do,

`count = hm.get(some_name)`

`hm.put(some_name,count+1)`,

Now traverse the map to find the key which has the highest value.
And the overall time and Space complexity will be O(N*M).

Hope this helps.